# Real difference between renewcommand and RenewDocumentCommand?

Tags: macros

I have a main file which calls several chapters with \include. For each chapter I rename the short name of the chapter with a renewcommand. This works fine but it doesn't anymore with RenewDocumentCommand.
Here are 3 MWE (they are really short but it is enough to understand the problem):

The first one works fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\newcommand\chap{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\chap}{Premier chapitre}
\chapter{Chapitre 1}\label{Chapitre:\chap}

Début du chapitre 1

\chap\quad\ref{Chapitre:\chap}%to see if everything is okay

\renewcommand{\chap}{Deuxième chapitre}
\chapter{Chapitre 2}\label{Chapitre:\chap}

Début du chapitre 2

\chap\quad\ref{Chapitre:\chap}%to see if everything is okay
\end{document}
```

Now, the second one with RenewDocumentCommand:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\NewDocumentCommand\chap{}{}

\begin{document}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chap}{}{Premier chapitre}
\chapter{Chapitre 1}\label{Chapitre:\chap}

Début du chapitre 1

\chap\quad\ref{Chapitre:\chap}%to see if everything is okay

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chap}{}{Deuxième chapitre}
\chapter{Chapitre 2}\label{Chapitre:\chap}

Début du chapitre 2

\chap\quad\ref{Chapitre:\chap}%to see if everything is okay
\end{document}
```

As you can see there are two problems:

- I have a warning:  Label `Chapitre:\chap ' multiply defined.
- the \chap command works fine but the reference \ref{Chapitre:\chap} doesn't work.
  I don't understand why it doesn't work whereas \chap works

So I tried to replace \label{Chapitre:\chap} by \label{Chapitre:Premier chapitre} and this works fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\NewDocumentCommand\chap{}{}

\begin{document}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chap}{}{Premier chapitre}
\chapter{Chapitre 1}\label{Chapitre:Premier chapitre}

Début du chapitre 1

\chap\quad\ref{Chapitre:\chap}%to see if everything is okay

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chap}{}{Deuxième chapitre}
\chapter{Chapitre 2}\label{Chapitre:Deuxième chapitre}

Début du chapitre 2

\chap\quad\ref{Chapitre:\chap}%to see if everything is okay
\end{document}
```

So, is there a real difference between renewcommand and RenewDocumentCommand? And am I doing something wrong?

PS: In my real files,

- the \newcommand{\chap}{} is in my main file
- the \renewcommand{\chap}{...} is in each chapter

Comment: Macros defined by `\(Re)NewDocumentCommand` are robust and don't expand in certain situations, as you've found out.

Comment: Seems to work if you use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` and `\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand`. Not sure if that is by chance.

Comment: @daleif no, by design

Comment: For simple data-storage inside a macro don't use `\(Re)New(Expandable)DocumentCommand`, stick to `\(re)newcommand` for this. There are good reasons to switch to the new interface, but not for usages like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I thought \newcommand and \NewDocumentCommand were identical but I was wrong. So I will stick to \(re)newcommand for data storage, as @Skillmon recommended me